# Why do the installed and most recent version numbers of Gwibber differ? 

Tags: 11.04, gwibber

My apologies if this has been asked before, but I noticed that on Gwibber's website, they list 2.30 as the most recent version of Gwibber. Yet when I open Gwibber in Natty, it lists the version installed as 3.0.0.1

Is this an Ubuntu specific version or is the site out of date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some information on Gwibber's website appears to be outdated. The latest blog post, titled [*Introducing Gwibber 2.30*](http://gwibber.com/blog/2010/04/introducing-gwibber-2-30/), was written in April 2010.

If you click the [Download](http://gwibber.com/download/) link on their site you'll see that they refer visitors to [version 3.0](https://launchpad.net/gwibber/3.0) for source code releases and to Ubuntu's repository (which also happens to be [version 3.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/gwibber)) for packaged releases.